# Declare and use variable in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am extremely beginner in MySQL Stored Procedure. So, sorry for the foolish question.
I am having problem at the 4th line.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE lastBatch INT DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT MAX(batch) FROM table2 INTO lastBatch; //this line creates error
  DECLARE rows CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE batch = lastBatch ;
END;
;;
```

Any help?

Comment: I'm getting 'Ýou have an error in SQL syntax;'.

Comment: 1) Do you remember about `DELIMITER`? 2) Any declaration must posess before any other statement.

Comment: @Akina Yes, I've DELIMITER in my code.

Comment: Please show code including delimiter